# MYSQL: Insert one value from another table while populating other columns regularly

Tags: mysql, insert, distinct

Lets say we have a table **(1)**:

```
id | col1 | col2
```

And another table **(2)**:

```
id | col3
```

Task is to insert all `col3` distinct values to `col1` at the same time populating `col2` with random integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions here.

This uses a sub query to return the distinct values of col2.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, col2)
SELECT NULL, col2, FLOOR(RAND()*(1000))+1
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col2
    FROM table2
)
```

The following abuses the GROUP BY clause to only generate rows for distinct values of col2. While this should be OK on a default install of MySQL, it might not work depending on the options set up for your installation and also probably wouldn't work in other flavours of SQL.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, col2)
SELECT NULL, col2, FLOOR(RAND()*(1000))+1
FROM table2
GROUP BY col2
```